# Tableview reload is not happening properly with new values from core data

Tags: swift4

First time reload works properly for UITableview, but second time it's not, before reloading data is ready but tableview not updating with new values in it. I am using core data to save values.

```
EisedoNetworkInterface.shared().rawDataApiWithParmeters(apiName: kCompletedTask, authorization : token, params: ["uID": UID,"i": taskId, "r": repeatTask, "d": dueDate,"rem": reminderDate], httpType: .POST, completionBlock: { (response, result, error) in


        OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
            if let success = result?["success"] as? Bool{
                let type = result?["type"] as? Int

                if type == 1{

                    if let tasksArray = result?["tasks"] as? [[String:Any]]{
                        for dic in tasksArray{
                            CoreDataManager.sharedManager.addTaskOnline(dic, fromFetchAllTask: true)
                        }
                        self.checkForTaskPriority()
                    }
                }
            }
            })
    })
```

And checkForTaskPriority functions as follows

```
func checkForTaskPriority(){

    let data = CoreDataManager.sharedManager.fetchOnlineTask()

    if let newData = data{
        for dic in newData{

            self.coreDoFirst?.append(dic)
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share more information with us, maybe some piece of code, or for instance, how the tableview know that there ir new data to be reloaded...

Comment: `if let tasksArray = result?["tasks"] as? [[String:Any]]{
                           print(tasksArray as Any)
                            for dic in tasksArray{
                                CoreDataManager.sharedManager.addTaskOnline(dic, fromFetchAllTask: true)
                            }
                            self.checkForTaskPriority()}`. In checkForTaskPriority priority method i am appending values to the array and after that reloading tableview

Comment: user3534730 is best to edit the body of the post with the new information.

Comment: Please check the edited post

Comment: Please, `if let _ = data { ... data!` is a horrible syntax. Don't do that.

Comment: Oh! Thank you, can you share any updates for above problem.